# Why is private route table not checked when network packages is going outbound?

Tags: amazon-vpc, subnet

I have a public network with a load balancer and a private subnet in AWS with EC2 instance as webserver.

The inbound traffic goes like this:
[image]

[image]

On the reverse path from the private network, there is no private route checked. Why is that? Should in between both acls acl-0d6fd not a route table of the private subnet being checked?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it's a bug in the analyzer.

In the document linked, AWS clearly states that the routing table on the private subnet is being checked for the return path:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/load-balancer-stickiness/subnets-routing.html

> The EC2 instance in the private subnet routes the outbound traffic
> through the route table.
>
> The route table has a local route to the public subnet. It reaches the
> Application Load Balancer on the node in the corresponding public
> subnet, by following the path back the way the traffic entered.